# React input value not working in child component

Tags: reactjs, react-lifecycle-hooks

I have two components. Child component will open in modal box. Modal box component will contain add and edit the user. I have passed some values for modal box input and getting that value in getDerivedStateFormProps life cycle hook. Initially it's populating the value to input value. But after that if type anything in the text box state is not updated. Please see the details below

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    state.show = props.show;
    state.company = props.company;
    return state;
  }
```

```
onChange = async(e) => {
    this.setState({company: {...this.state.company, [e.target.name]: e.target.value}});
  }
```

But the state is not updating. Could anyone please provide help to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the code around these little snippets to give us some context.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mutate the `state` parameter.

The correct usage of `getDerivedStateFromProps` is to return an object which is shallow-merged into the component's existing `state`.

```js
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props) {
    const {show, company} = props;
    return {show, company};
}
```

Also, `getDerivedStateFromProps` will be called by React *after* applying state from your call to `this.setState`. That means any change to `company` in `getDerivedStateFromProps` will clobber the change to `company` in `this.setState`.

Comment: Sure, but I have shown you how to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` correctly. Most likely the cause of your non-working code lies within the code you have **not** posted in the question.